# Asymptotics of the smallest integer for which the number of divisors is the $n$-th prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, asymptotics

I am interested in the function $f(n)$ defined on the positive integers where $f(n)$ is the smallest integer for which the number of divisors is the $n$-th prime.  Is there a simple asymptotic  form for this function?

The first few values of this function are $2, 4, 16, 64, 1024, 4096$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of divisors of some number n is a prime number, n must be a prime power.
Therefore , $2^{p-1}$ is the least number having p divisors for any prime p.

Comment: Thanks. If the $n$th prime asymptotically is $n\log n$ then would you get $n^n/2$ as the answer?

Comment: $$2^{n\log n} = e^{n\log n\log 2} = n^{n\log 2}.$$ That's somewhat slower growth than $n^n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Do you think that is the exact asymptotics?

Comment: @felix It's not exact, but pretty good. You have $\lvert p_n - n\log n\rvert \leqslant C\cdot n\log \log n$ (for $n > 2$), so you are within a factor of $$2^{\pm Cn\log \log n} = (\log n)^{\pm C'n} = n^{\pm C'n \frac{\log\log n}{\log n}}$$ of the exact value. $n^{n\log 2}$ is the principal term, but the remaining factor is not bounded. However, it grows much slower.